# Is there such a thing as force swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

So I know there's now force touch on the apple watch and I was just wondering if there was a force swipe recognizer. Like can the apple watch sense how hard you are pushing on the screen while you swipe?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Force Touch API is very restricted and there isn't an official solution for your problem, it isn't possible.